# Set Progress of Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a Async Task that does not add the percentage while it is going through the task. It always stays at 0% 0/100

Here is my code

```
     private class getAppInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(showLoading == true){
             dialog = new ProgressDialog(SelfHelp.this);
             dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
             dialog.setMessage("Loading");
             dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
             dialog.setCancelable(false);   
             dialog.setMax(100);
             dialog.setProgress(100);
             dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {                       
        String xml = null;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            while(count != 100){
                publishProgress(""+count);
                count += 5;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                

        Document doc = parser.GetDomElement(xml);
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("topic");
        getChildElements(nl);                           
        return xml;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.v("count",progress[0]);
        dialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {    
        //dialog.setProgress(100);
        menuList.setAdapter(setListItems(menuItems));
        menuList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        if(showLoading == true){
            dialog.dismiss();
            showLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

It does go into `onProgressUpdate` and the count goes up by 5 but the progress bar does not change. How can I have it increment by 5 and show the progress properly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your issue is related to `setIndeterminate(true)`: You should set it to `false` if you want to have progress update. if you `setIndeterminate(true)` then the ProgressDialog will work as the classic Windows Hourglass

Comment: That suggestion didnt change anything. It still hasn't moved passed 0%

Comment: set dialog.setProgress(100); to 0 instead of 100

Comment: setting the progress in the preExecute to 0 still did not work

Comment: dialog.setIndeterminate(true); set it to false

Comment: That did it. That setIndeterminate was messing it up. Thanks
What does that do anyway?

Comment: the indetermiante progress dialog is something like the windows hourglass. I will update my answer. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following code, It is showing progress in % ratio, here is the code,

```
public class ProgressBarExampleActivity extends Activity 
{
    ProgressThread progThread;
    ProgressDialog progDialog;
    Button button1, button2;
    int typeBar;                     // Determines type progress bar: 0 = spinner, 1 = horizontal
    int delay = 1000;                  // Milliseconds of delay in the update loop
    int maxBarValue = 30;           // Maximum value of horizontal progress bar

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//      // Process button to start spinner progress dialog with anonymous inner class
//      button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
//      button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
//      {
//          public void onClick(View v) 
//          {
//              typeBar = 0;
//              showDialog(typeBar);
//          }
//      }); 

        // Process button to start horizontal progress bar dialog with anonymous inner class
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                typeBar = 1;
                showDialog(typeBar);
            }
        }); 
    }

    // Method to create a progress bar dialog of either spinner or horizontal type
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
        switch(id) 
        {
//      case 0:                      // Spinner
//          progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//          progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
//          progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//          progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
//          progThread.start();
//          return progDialog;
        case 1:                      // Horizontal
            progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progDialog.setMax(maxBarValue);
            progDialog.setMessage("Dollars in checking account:");
            progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
            progThread.start();
            return progDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Handler on the main (UI) thread that will receive messages from the 
    // second thread and update the progress.

    final Handler handler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
            // and update the progress bar.
            int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
            progDialog.setProgress(total);
//          if (total >= maxBarValue)
            if (total <= 0 )            
            {
                dismissDialog(typeBar);
                progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
            }
        }
    };

    // Inner class that performs progress calculations on a second thread.  Implement
    // the thread by subclassing Thread and overriding its run() method.  Also provide
    // a setState(state) method to stop the thread gracefully.

    private class ProgressThread extends Thread 
    {   
        // Class constants defining state of the thread
        final static int DONE = 0;
        final static int RUNNING = 1;

        Handler mHandler;
        int mState;
        int total;

        // Constructor with an argument that specifies Handler on main thread
        // to which messages will be sent by this thread.

        ProgressThread(Handler h) 
        {
            mHandler = h;
        }

        // Override the run() method that will be invoked automatically when 
        // the Thread starts.  Do the work required to update the progress bar on this
        // thread but send a message to the Handler on the main UI thread to actually
        // change the visual representation of the progress. In this example we count
        // the index total down to zero, so the horizontal progress bar will start full and
        // count down.

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            mState = RUNNING;   
            total = maxBarValue;
            while (mState == RUNNING) 
            {
                // The method Thread.sleep throws an InterruptedException if Thread.interrupt() 
                // were to be issued while thread is sleeping; the exception must be caught.
                try 
                {
                    // Control speed of update (but precision of delay not guaranteed)
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Thread was Interrupted");
                }

                // Send message (with current value of  total as data) to Handler on UI thread
                // so that it can update the progress bar.

                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("total", total);
                msg.setData(b);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                total--;    // Count down
            }
        }

        // Set current state of thread (use state=ProgressThread.DONE to stop thread)
        public void setState(int state) 
        {
            mState = state;
        }
    }
}
```

See the output,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will mention another aproach, because I came across this solution when I was looking for some practical way how to communicate from my Service running AsyncTask back to main UI. Lucifer's solution is not modular for Services, if you need to use your Service in more then 1 class (that was my case), you won't be able to access variable handler and as far as I know you can't even send Handler as Intent to Service (you can send it to AsyncTask tho). Solution is broadcasting.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(WORK_DONE));
```

in AsyncTask and

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) { //update your UI here }
}

registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(WORK_DONE));
```

in your activity.

I don't like all those inner classes android developers use. I understand it's easier to create inner class and access outer class variables, but once you need to use the class again your doomed and you have to edit the code! I am realy new to Android, maybe I am wrong and you actually don't need to reuse those classes. Never did a bigger project so I have no idea but it just doesn't feel right, since on college, they tried hard to teach us how to programm reusable code.